# Finding the length of each set of successive values using python or excel

Tags: python, excel

I have a python list/excel range that looks like

```
[0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0] .
```

I want the following output:

```
length of 1st set of zeros - 4

length of 2nd set of zeros - 2

length of 3rd set of zeros - 1

length of 4th set of zeros - 7

length of 5th set of zeros - 3
```

I've tried the formula `" COUNTIF($D2:D$2,D2)"` in Excel which helps me find the nth value, but I'm not sure how to find the length of each set of successive values.

How can the above be achieved in Excel as well as Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
counter = 1
suffixes = {1: 'st', 2:'nd', 3:'rd'}
for key, group in itertools.groupby(the_sequence):
    if key == 0:
        print 'The length of {}{} sequence of zeros is: {}'.format(counter,
                                                                   suffixes.get(counter, 'th'),
                                                                   len(tuple(group)))
        counter += 1
```

That outputs:

```
The length of 1st sequence of zeros is: 4
The length of 2nd sequence of zeros is: 2
The length of 3rd sequence of zeros is: 1
The length of 4th sequence of zeros is: 7
The length of 5th sequence of zeros is: 3
```

Unfortunately I'm not an excel user and I can't help you with the Excel solution.

Answer (score 3):

In Excel, assuming you have data in `D2:D20` you can use this "array formula" in F2

`=IFERROR(INDEX(FREQUENCY(IF($D$2:$D$20=0,ROW($D$2:$D$20)),IF(OFFSET($D$2:$D$20,1,0)<>0,IF($D$2:$D$20=0,ROW($D$2:$D$20)))),ROWS(F$2:F2)),"")`

confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER and copied down - That will give you a list of all the zero sequence lengths - when the numbers run out you get blanks

If data is in a row rather than a column you need to revise that slightly.....

Comment: Great work Barry. Works like a charm... Will upvote you once I have the reputation sir!!

Comment: @richie you still need 1 more upvote at the moment) don't worry - I'll upvote barry's answer - it's always a masterpiece worth to be favorited)